How can I ensure that the snackbar remains visible and not hidden behind the modal bottom sheet on Compose?
TL-DR -> How can I ensure that the snackbar remains visible and not hidden behind the modal bottom sheet? What is the reason of it?
I'm creating a Snackbar using snackbarHost and snackBarHostState in a Scaffold. Additionally, in the content of the Scaffold, I conditionally include or remove a ModalBottomSheet based on a boolean value. My goal is to display the Snackbar while the ModalBottomSheet is visible. I can see the Snackbar when I dismiss the bottom sheet, but I can't see it while the bottom sheet is open. I tried adding zIndex(1000f) to the modifier of SnackbarHost. I also tried wrapping SnackbarHost in a Popup and a Box, but none of these solutions worked. How can I display the Snackbar above the ModalBottomSheet? And what is the reason of this situation? The structure of my code is similar to the following. (btw I use material3 library)
Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier,
        snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackBarHostState) },
        ...
    ) { 

        LaunchedEffect(key1 = message) {
            snackBarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = message,
                duration = SnackbarDuration.Long
                )
            }

        ...

        if (showBottomSheet) {
            ModalBottomSheet(...) 
        }
    }


Does this answer your question? Jetpack compose snackbar hidden behind bottomsheet

Nope didn't worked in my case

And I am curious about the reason this answer is just suggesting a solution

The issue arises because the snackbar is defined before the bottom sheet in your code. Therefore, when the bottom sheet is visible, it should hide the snackbar since the snackbar is positioned behind it.

I changed the position of it but seems not working again. Seems like the Modal bottom sheet has its own window and it printed onto other compose components window.
